# Cluetip for every dynamically generated row in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cluetip

I would like to display [cluetip [jQuery] plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#getting-started) for every row of dynamic grid in .aspx  page. The content in cluetip should be fetched from database dynamically while loading the cluetip plugin.

Can anyone suggest any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

the thing with the dynamic content is easy (when you now how) ^^
just append an id as an GET-Var on the link (test.com$id=3) and catch it within the cluetip-content ($id = $_GET['id']).

There is still another way with the ajax-settings, but it doesn't work well for me

Cheers,
Chris